# How to make named pipe accessible for non-elevated processes?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes, uac, wasapi

Problem: 
I created a service, which is supposed to run under elevated privileges. Now I have an application accessible to users. The application wants to speak to the service via a named pipe. The named pipe is created by the service.

However I cannot open the pipe, because ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Question: how I can setup the pipe in the service in order the application would be able to write-open it ?

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-security-and-access-rights) however it doesn't help at all. I'd be happy to see hints or code sample(s).

Background:
I need to change settings of an Audio Device what can be done via IPropertyStore inteface gotten via IMMDevice::OpenPropertyStore call. However the documentation clearly says that I cannot do this if I don't have administrative privileges. Obviously I don't want to annoy user with UAC each time he is going to rotate a knob. so for this I created the aforementioned service. But no luck again.

Comment: specify a security descriptor for a named pipe when you create it. this security descriptor must allow open it for not elevated processes. most simply case - just set 0 in *DACL*

Comment: No luck so far, I tried to pass default one, created via InitializeSecurityDescriptor, as well as I tried customized one taken from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--

Comment: how i say - minimal worked solution - https://pastebin.com/9XGk3gGu - set 0 dacl. begin from it. then if want you can instead 0 dacl use not empty dacl say with  logon SID on the DACL

Comment: Thanks!!! it helped. I missed that setting 0 dacl is not equal to "absent" dacl. Unfortunately I cannot accept your answer because it's a comment ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for control access to [*Securable Object*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/securable-objects) we need set appropriate  a security descriptor. of course system always by default set some [security descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptors) on new created object based on caller [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-tokens) ( *The default DACL that the system uses when the user creates a securable object without specifying a security descriptor*) (we can change this DACL with [`TokenDefaultDacl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class) if want )

the most simply solution for enable very wide access for object set *NULL* (not empty !! empty DACL dissable access for all) DACL in security descriptor. this allow access almost for everyone too object (except Low Integrity thread/process (for this need set *Low Mandatory Label* is *SACL*)

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, 0, FALSE);
SetSecurityDescriptorControl(&sd, SE_DACL_PROTECTED, SE_DACL_PROTECTED);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), &sd, FALSE};
```

and then we you pointer to `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` in create object api (almost all this api take pointer to `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` as parameter. if use native api - pointer to Security Descriptor was inside [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/ff557749(v=vs.71)) structure)

another possible choice - use not NULL but another DACL, here most hard point decide what concrete must be in this DACL. not implementation, but conceptual choice.